# Why Can My Browser Access Files via `file://127.0.0.1/c$/` but not `file://127.0.0.1/c:/`?

Tags: windows, browser, url

I use Edge on MS-Windows; I didn't change any advanced network configurations.

I tried to access local files in three ways:

1. `file://localhost/c:/` works
2. `file://127.0.0.1/c:/` doesn't
3. `file://127.0.0.1/c$/` does

Why the 2nd method doesn't work and the 3rd (weird format) does??

Comment: Try asking in SuperUser.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: @ewokx: OK, thx.  I've voted to close to move it to superuser.se

Answer (score 1):

The $ symbol following the drive letter indicates a hidden share that is active by default on all Windows systems. It is typically locked down only to admin access, but that's more applicable in an enterprise environment.

I cannot speak to why one work or the other, as I am not sure why, but the "weird format" is entirely normal, not weird.